# Выборка данных из нескольких таблиц в yii2 с условием

Tags: yii2

Задача. Необходимо выбрать все данные из таблици posts и к этим данным присоединить поле name из таблицы categories(где post.category-id = categories.id), которое обозначает категорию к которой относится публикация. Как это сделать при помощи active record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно сама модель

```
class Post extend ActiveRecord {

    //Релейшен на категорию
    public function getCategory(){
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category-id']);
    }
}

//Такой пост существует
if($model = Post::findOne(1)){
   //У этого поста есть категория
   if($category = $model->category){
      //Получаем имя категории
      echo category->name;
   }
}
```

Comment: нет. в этом случае я получу два объекта и не смогу нормально перебрать все данные в одном цикле

Comment: C какого это счастья у вас будет два объекта? Объектов у вас будет столько, сколько постов вы вытащите из базы. В данном случае **findOne** как бы намекает, что объект один

Comment: Все. Я понял как это работает, спасибо.